# How to check if a single letter (which has been input as a string variable) is equal to any character in another string?

Tags: python, string, character

I am trying to make a hangman game at the minute and this is the code so far:

```
word = raw_input("Please enter a word")

correctguesses = []
wrongguesses = []

guesscorrect = False

while guesscorrect == False:
    guess = raw_input("Guess a letter")
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print "Your guess was more than one letter"
    for i in word:
        if guess == i in word:
            print "correct"
            correctguesses.append(guess)
    print "here are your correct guesses so far" ,(''.join(correctguesses))
    for i in word:
        if guess != i in word:
            print "incorrect"
            wrongguesses.append(guess)
    print "here are your wrong guesses so far:", (''.join(wrongguesses))
```

my output:

```
correct/
here are your correct guesses so far:/ e/
incorrect/
incorrect/
incorrect/
incorrect/
here are your wrong guesses so far:/ eeee/
```

It is doing that because it isn't the correct letter for the 4 other letters in hello (which was the word).

Answer (score 0):

```
word = raw_input("Please enter a word")

correctguesses = []
wrongguesses = []

guesscorrect = False

while guesscorrect == False:
    guess = raw_input("Guess a letter")
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print "Your guess was more than one letter"
        continue #to prompt for input again
    for i in word:
        if guess == i: #i will be a letter in the word
            print "correct"
            correctguesses.append(guess)
    print "here are your correct guesses so far" ,(''.join(correctguesses))


    for i in word:
        if guess != i: #put this case in the else block of the if in the previous loop and remove this loop
            print "incorrect"
            wrongguesses.append(guess)
    print "here are your wrong guesses so far:", (''.join(wrongguesses))
```

I have commented some of the details. 
This [course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x8) might help with basics of python and programming.